# VueResource Vue.http.get Response Status Code 0

Tags: ajax, node.js, express, vue.js, vue-resource

im having this issue where i send a request to the API to retrieve all users, the login function is called(index.vue) when called it tries to go to api/users/all which in this case should return all the users in that collection.

using Postman the API returns the correct results and if i console.log the output in the routeUsers before i send the response back, it outputs all the correct data to the console

when it returns to index.vue, the response status code is 0.

ive had a look online and some things are mentioning about CORS Headers but i dont think thats applicable to me and other things about the response has been cancelled,

can anyone shed some light on this for me and help me try to fix it?!

API main.js

```js
var app = express();
var users = require('./routes/routeUsers');


app.use('/users', users);


module.exports = app;
```

api/models/users.js

```js
var db = require('../Utilities/db')


module.exports.all = function(cb) {
  var collection = db.get().collection('users')
  collection.find().toArray(function(err, docs) {
    cb(err, docs)
  })
}
```

api/routes/routeUsers.js

```js
var express = require('express')
  , router = express.Router()

var user = require('../models/users');


router.get('/all', function(req, res) {
  user.all(function(err, users) {
    res.send(users);
  })
})
```

Index.vue

```js
export default {
data: function () {
    return {
        username: '',
        password: '',
        users: []
     }
},   
methods: {
  login: function() {
  Vue.http.get('/api/users/all').then((response) => {
       console.log("SUCCESS",response);   
       this.users = response.body;
       console.log(users);
    }, function (error) {
        console.log("Error", error.status);        // handle error
      });
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that the inputs were in a form tag. removed Form tag and worked fine.